# Indians traveling to Georgia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, georgia-country

I have Indian passport with valid Schengen visa and Georgian e-visa. Can I have trip to Georgia. Because I'm hearing lots of news that travelling to Georgia is turning out to be a nightmare for many Indians. Most of them being deported and had been treated badly @ Tbilisi airport

Comment: Where are you hearing this news?  Some citations might be helpful (ideally from reliable sources such as news sites).

Answer (score 4):

You only need either a Georgian e-visa **or** a Schengen visa, not both.

Furthermore, most Georgian border officers don't speak English, and so you will rarely be questioned about your trip. Just in case, though, bring confirmations of your return trip and your accommodation in Georgia.

Comment: +1 for completely correct info. Though, to further put the OP's mind at ease, I can confirm that as an Indian citizen I've never had any issues entering Georgia multiple times using only a UK resident permit or US visa. The cases of entry refusals are true, however, they are also very few and most people do not face any issues. That being said, I have definitely been asked more questions while entering Georgia than any other country that I've traveled to.